# Get href value Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-directive

**My HTML**

```
<a href="##product.like_url##" df-like-product class="icon-like trigger animated v-a-m" data-id="##product.id##" data-type="product" ng-class="{active:product.liked_by_user}"></a>
```

I wan't to get the href value in my directive but everytime i get the variable name

I get returned `##product.like_url##`

when i inspect the element the url is correct filled in.

This is my directive

```
df.directives.directive('dfLikeProduct', function($window) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      // Props
      var $element = $(element);
      var $amount = $element.prev();
      var url = $element.attr('href');

      // Methods
      var likeProduct = function(){
        $.post(url, function(data){ 
          if (data == 1) {
            element.removeClass('unlike').addClass('active like');
            var num = parseFloat($amount.text());
            $amount.text(++num);
          } else if (data == -1) {
            element.removeClass('active like').addClass('unlike');
            var num = parseFloat($amount.text());
            $amount.text(--num);
          }
        }).fail(function(){
          $window.location.href = '/login';
        });
      }


      // Listeners
      $element.on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(url);
        //likeProduct();
      });


      // Init

    }
  };
});
```

Comment: what are you trying to achieve !! read your post do you think it conveys what actually u want

Comment: I wan't the value of the href in my directive so i can do a POST request

Comment: you can't use Laravel variables inside an angular variable;  One is server side, the other is client side.  If angular generated the link, it won't ever be sent to your server to be evaluated and replaced by Laravel.  conversely, if the variable is supposed to be replaced by Laravel, angular is still going to see the value before the server has made the replacement.

Answer (score 1):

At first you need to use `ng-href` instead of just `href`.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref

And you can get this using `$link.attr('ng-href');`

Here is another one useful link:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element

Comment: Oke and than i want the value from the ng-href?

Comment: when i do this i just get ##product.like_url## returned and not the actual link

Comment: Wait, it's your expression `##product.like_url##`? If I do not confused, it must look like this: `{{product.like_url}}`

Comment: No it's that because i use it inside blade template from laravel, if i inspect the element all values are correct it's very strange

Comment: Can you create jsfiddle please? It's hard to think on the fly

Comment: It has something to do with interpolated